# `File.exist?` won't find file that exists

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use `File.exist?` to have a dynamic background. When I try to to point File.exist? to a specific file it doesn't seem to find it.

```
image_path = "../assets/" + city_code + ".jpg"
if 
  File.exist?('#{image_path}')
  @image = image_path
else
  @image = "../assets/coastbanner.jpg"
end
```

If I remove replace `city_code` with a path that I know exists, it still won't find it. I must bee missing something small.

I wanted to be a little more clear:  If I remove the interpolation/variable and replace it with a path that I know works, '../assets/coastbanner.jpg' for example, it still will not work.  In fact, no valid path seems to get it to yield a true response.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Though you were able to get your answer, this question comes from a more-principle mistake about usage of the language, rather than a problem with the `File.exist?` interface.  Try to always validate core assumptions, and develop debugging techniques.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you.  You're right, I should have been more clear about what attempts or modifications I've attempted.  In fact, I've already tried each answer that was provided with no resolve. Had I provided what I've tried, I could have saved people time.  I appreciate the input.

Comment: Check if you're running this code in the directory you think you're running it in. You can use Dir.pwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your code:

- String interpolation works only with double quotes
- There is no need for a string interpolation when the variable is a string already
- the condition belongs in the same line than the `if`

Furthermore the folder in which the server is running might not be the same folder than the current webpage is served from. That said it might make sense to use absolute path for image links and path including `Rails.root` for the `File.exist?` test.

I am not sure about your application's folder structure, but something like the following should work:

```
image_path = "/assets/#{city_code}.jpg"

if File.exist?(Rails.root.join('app', image_path))
  @image = image_path
else
  @image = '/assets/coastbanner.jpg'
end
```

Tip: Test with the `coastbanner.jpg` to get the image apth correct and then with the `File.exist?` to get the path in the app.

Comment: Hey, the single quotes are there because I had already tried double quotes.  Something I did in desperation.  Removing the interpolation doesn't get it to work either.   What's odd is that '../assets/coastbanner.jpg' will load perfectly, but if I insert that in to the File.exist? I will get false.  In other words, when I put a perfectly good path in my File.exist?, it still wont respond as true.

Comment: Boom!  There it is.  I had to read up on Rails.root, since it's new to me, but it did the trick.

Comment: `image_path = "../assets/#{city_code}.jpg"
    if File.exist?(Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', "#{city_code}.jpg"))
      @image = image_path
    else
      @image = "../assets/coastbanner.jpg"
    end`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes for the string interpolation to work.

```
File.exist?("#{image_path}")
```

In this case, you could actually just use the variable since it already is the string you want.

```
File.exist?(image_path)
```

If you want to use the `#{}` feature, a good place to use it is when creating `image_path`.

```
image_path = "../assets/#{city_code}.jpg"
```

Comment: I actually had double quotes prior to the single quotes, in attempt to get this to work.  Neither single nor double quotes makes a difference.  Nor does removing the interpolation and simply leaving the variable...

Comment: How do you end up using `image_path`? Do you put it in an image tag? Or use `File.read`? Or something else?

Comment: I'm new to programming, so bare with me.  But when a search is preformed, I want to display an image of the searched city, but if there is no image for that city, then I want to display a default photo.  So if the city_code in the image_path finds a matching file, the @image is then used in my view to display the background.  `<style media="screen">
  .header-section { background-image: url(<%= @image %>); }
</style>`

Answer (score 1):

```
if 
  File.exist?( image_path )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't get it to work.  I edited the question, and wanted to point out, that any valid path I put in the File.exist? will not yield a true response.  If i replace image_path with '../assets/coastbanner.jpg' it still responds as false, even though that file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can have `#{}` in a string with single quotes. Try double-quoting it.

Comment: Or, in this case, just remove the quotes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using with in a Rails application, and if so, the most probable cause would be:

When Rails creates `assets` it creates a digest. Because of this your image name might have a digest string in the name. So I suggest to use `image_path` or `asset_path`

Ex: `File.exist?(image_path("#{city_code}.jpg"))`

But having said that, proper was to handle these kind of cases would be to have a flag in the database if you want to set the the custom image or not. Because it's much faster than accessing the file system.